# How to handle page relationships in Grav CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, relationship, grav

I currently have a few projects pages and I’m looking to display a list of team members that are associated with each project (a member may be associated with multiple projects) but I’m not sure how I can create this. A taxonomy doesn’t provide enough information (ideally want to show an image with name and short bio) so I’m assuming I’ll need to create a /team-members/ page with member pages below it and pull this in somehow to each project.

How would I go about allowing team members to be added to projects through the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can create a page for each team member. These page can be unvisible if you don't want to display them alone

Then you create one page for each project.

When you want to use one member page as a part of one project page, you just include it:

```
{{ page.find('/some/other.page').content }}
```

Note that the above code may require you to activate twig parsing on your pages.

This way you can include the same team member in several project pages and update team member content in only one place from the admin panel.

Another approach is to create a plugin that will enable you to manage projects and member as you want to, but it may be a little overkill given Grav can do what you want out of the box.